# HD Pro Webcam C920 microphone not being recognized by Google Hangouts, or Zoom on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, webcam

I don't really know how to trouble shoot this. The camera sometimes isn't recognized either. Is there a different webcam I need to buy, or is there a way to help Ubuntu recongnize this one. I've tried unplugging and plugging in the USB. Can't seem to locate drivers to install anywhere.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the Google Hangouts Video call with the Logitech Capture app closed. I was running into the same issue and noticed that I had left the app running in the background. The app was set to record because I forgot to stop recording and close the app. Once I did that, Google hangouts had no problems recognizing my C920.